# Does C Standard guarantee diagnostic message for #error directive?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I have some trouble understanding semantics of `5.1.1.3/1` *Diagnostics* subclause from N1570 C11 draft (emphasis mine):

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined. **Diagnostic messages need not be produced in other circumstances**.<sup>9</sup>

I understand that the intent was to exclude (non-constraint) undefined behavior (thus that are no diagnostics on e.g. buffer overflow), but what about `#error` directive? As in `6.10.5/1` *Error directive*:

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> `# error` *pp-tokens<sub>opt</sub>* new-line
>
> causes the implementation to **produce a diagnostic message** that includes the specified sequence of preprocessing tokens.

Does these both subclauses are not mutually exclusive?

For some other reference see also [DR#176](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_176.html).

Comment: I suppose the intent was that `#error` should always produce a diagnostic message, but this wasn't mentioned in the former clause.

Comment: IIRC Keith Thompson said that the error directive was the only place where an implementation is required to produce a diagnostic.

Comment: "need not be produced" does not mean "cannot be produced".

Comment: @remyabel: I would argue to this point as "shall produce" (`5.1.1.3/1`) means that "conforming implementation is required to" and this subclause is normative.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski Precisely, "shall" actually means "must" in this context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C99 went a step further than the suggested resolution for that DR. Instead of requiring a diagnostic, they require treating it as an error.

> **4. Conformance**
>
> 4 The implementation shall not successfully translate a preprocessing translation unit
>   containing a `#error` preprocessing directive unless it is part of a group skipped by
>   conditional inclusion.

Now, strictly speaking, perhaps you're right that an implementation *could* choose to refuse to compile a program containing an `#error` directive *without* issuing a diagnostic, claiming that 5.1.1.3 allows it to ignore the semantics for `#error`. However, an implementation that goes to such lengths to being as useless as possible within the bounds set by the standard, would easily work around any attempt to require a diagnostic: the implementation could simply dump the complete preprocessor output (including anything following `#error`), and follow that by "there's an error in there somewhere". Because of that, it effectively doesn't matter whether the standard requires a diagnostic. There's no excuse for an implementation not to do so, and very little that the standard could to do force unwilling implementors.

Comment: When a C source file has been successfully translated, that would imply that there must exist somewhere a file which may, possibly with additional processing, be used to generate a runnable program.  Does the standard say anything about the state of the universe when compilation fails?  Unless the standard requires that the compiler ensure that nothing resembling the expected output file exists when compilation fails, I'm not sure what a mandated failure would mean.

Answer (score 4):

As someone who served on the committee, our response to a question like this would often begin with a phrase along the lines of "A careful reading of the standard ...", which is not quite as glib as it sounds. the language used is very specific. Consider the first clause

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic
>   message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a
>   preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a
>   violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is
>   also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined.
>   Diagnostic messages need not be produced in other circumstances.9

This clause is explicitly referring to a "violation of any syntax rule or constraint". A well formed `#error` directive does not, therefore, trigger this clause. Thus it does not apply, and mutual-exclusion is moot.

Also note the final sentence, where it says that diagnostics **" need not be produced "**. The term "need not" does not imply "must not". It simply means the implementation has the option whether or not to issue a diagnostic for other conditions (for example, style concerns). But again this entire clause is irrelevant for `#error`

Your second quote simply states exactly what an implementation must do for a well-formed  `#error` directive.

Comment: "It simply means the implementation has the option whether or not to issue a diagnostic". But in case of `#error` diagnostic message is always obligated (well, unless it's in e.g. `#if` directive with false condition, but it's not matter of implementation). I am not implying that "need not be produced" means "must not be produced", but that "there is no **obligation** for diagnostic meesage to be produced in other circumstances.". I hope my point is clear.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But, as I said, that sentence is part of a clause which applies to syntax violations. It can be mind bending to get your head around standardese. Try working with some of the communications standards :)

Comment: This answer surely cannot be right. The whole point of "Diagnostic messages need not be produced in other circumstances." is that it applies to programs that *don't* violate any syntax rule or constraint. A typical example would probably be `int main(void) { 1 / 0; }`, for which it specifies that no diagnostic is required. `#error Hello` / `int main(void) { }` violates no syntax rule or constraint either.

Comment: "need not" indeed does not mean "must not".  But it still is mutually exclusive with "must" or "shall".  As you correctly said, "need not" means the compiler DOES have the option whether to issue a diagnostic in other cases.  And the rule for `#error` says that the compiler DOES NOT have that option.  It surely is contradictory.